# Depth first search sub meshes

Tags: c++, json, algorithm

I'm trying to print all the submeshes of a giving scene node.. it's basically a depth first search. I'm trying to output the json values as level 1, level 2, until last child then output " "

seems I'm missing something that I can't understand the recursion probably

UPDATE: HERE IS ANOTHER TRIAL:

```
void AssimpLoader::WriteSubMeshesToJson(const aiScene* mScene,  const aiNode* pNode,  Json::StyledWriter &writer, std::ofstream &myfile, int level, Json::Value root )
{
    // if we have meshes
    if( pNode == nullptr)
    {
        // write to disk
        Ogre::LogManager::getSingleton().logMessage(" for mesh '" + Ogre::String( pNode->mName.data ) + "'" );
        Json::Value parameter;
        parameter["level0"];
        root.append(parameter);
        std::string output = writer.write(root);
        myfile << output;
        level = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        Json::Value parameter;
        level++;
        parameter["Level " + std::to_string(level)] = Ogre::String( pNode->mName.data) ;
        root.append(parameter);
        std::string output = writer.write(root);
        myfile << output;
    }
    // Traverse all child nodes of the current node instance
    for( unsigned int childIdx=0; childIdx < pNode->mNumChildren; childIdx++ )
    {
        const aiNode* pChildNode = pNode->mChildren[ childIdx ];
        WriteSubMeshesToJson(mScene, pChildNode, writer, myfile,level, root);


    }



}
```

What I need the json to be like this

```
{
      "Parenting1" : {
         "Parenting2" : {
            "Parenting3" : {}
         }
      }
}
```

Comment: This won't run as-is, but it is odd that you loop over "meshes," but don't actually use idx. You seem to just write the same mName.data over and over.

Comment: @KennyOstrom Can you post an answer with a fix ?

Comment: Please better explain what doesn't *work* in your implementation. From your code I understood that the printed `level` where not correct, but other readers may not understand the purpose or your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
void WriteSubMeshesToJson(..., std::ofstream &myfile, int &level)
----------------------------------------------------------^
```

Because you use a reference to the `level` variable, your increment is visible in the parent call after you finished printing the current child. It should not, the `level` value in the function should not change when you print a child mesh.

Just remove the `&` to use a pass by value argument.

You have the opposite problem for your `Json::Value`, you should pass it by reference so that children can insert themselves in the parent json. And you should fix your call to `WriteSubMeshesToJson` to pass the current node instead of always passing the `root` node.

By the way, your code isn't very idiomatic for C++. So here is a suggestion: There is no need to format the string manually before sending it to the file, you can as well use the `<<` operator directly on the `std::ostream`

```
std::string output;
level++;
output = "level" +  std::to_string(level) + + pNode->mName.data+ "\n";
myfile << output;
```

Becomes:

```
output << "level" << level << pNode->mName.data << '\n';
```

Comment: Thanks so much, I have another problem, which appending the json value into the root level, it keeps adding each level into the output file

Comment: please look at the updated code with the fix you mentioned

Comment: @andreahmed Please don't edit your question in a way that prevent users to understand the initial problem. If you want to give details, edit your question. Do not just comment an answer.

Comment: I can't append the results into json, level by level